# Using DataFrame.foreachPartition, processing partitions as data frames

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I have a dataframe that's partitioned by `col0`; there are many rows in the DF per value of `col0`. I have a database from which I want to fetch batches of data using the values of `col0` in each partition, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use `foreachPartition`, since it returns a `Iterator[Row]`.

Here's pseudocode for what I'm wanting to do:

```
var df = spark.read.parquet(...).repartition(numPartitions, "col0")
df.foreachPartition((part_df : DataFrame) => {
  val values = part_df.select("col0").distinct
  val sql = "select * from table0 where col0 in (${values})" // or some smarter method :)
  val db_df = spark.read.jdbc(..., table = sql)
  part_df.join(db_dv, "col0") // and/or whatever else
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an elegant solution to this, but I was able to find an inelegant one.

When you write out to a filesystem, Spark will write a separate file for each partition. You can then use filesystem to list the files, then read in and operate on each one individually as a separate dataframe.